# how to re-create .gitignore file after accidental removal

Tags: git

I accidentally deleted the gitignore file in one of the directories before pushing it upstream. Is there a way to re-create that file from the command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.gitignore` file is no different than any other file under version control. If you would like to get it back from `HEAD`, just do (wherever it was)

```
git checkout -- .gitignore
```

If you have deleted the file before adding it to the index or committing it, it is unfortunately lost and you'll have to recreate it (using your favorite text editor).